# How to call Microsoft Graph API from Java application

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to build a Java application which will use Microsoft Graph API in order to view files on SharePoint. Can anyone suggest any github urls or demo projects or a third party libraries available on maven

```
                    .
```

Comment: What is wrong with the official microsoft graph sdk for java?? https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java

Answer (score 0):

You can start building your java application by following the doc - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java

You can write below code to [get files on SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java)

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

LinkedList<Option> requestOptions = new LinkedList<Option>();
requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("expand", "fields"));

ListItem listItem = graphClient.sites("{site-id}").lists("{list-id}").items("{item-id}")
    .buildRequest( requestOptions )
    .get();
```

Comment: Where should i pass my organization SharePoint url ? In auth provider I can only set client id , client secret and tenant id. Please help me with this part. Rest part i have followed on how to get list or drive , etc.

Comment: In auth provider you have to add client id , client secret and tenant id and you have to write your URL in the form on graphClient.sites("{site-id}").lists("{list-id}").items("{item-id}") , I would suggest you to go with graph explorer first and try to get list items in the SharePoint , i help you to understand, thanks.

Comment: Where do i pass my college url ? Https://college.sharepoint.com/sites/MySite ??? after that i got how to fetch subsites and list, etc.